# Django HTML: Background Image only shows on one templates html file and not on other templates

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, background-image

I'm making a portfolio website using django. My templates are master.html, home.html, about.html, all_categories.html, app_projects.html, and project.html. Every html files extends to the master.html and the master.html loads static. I don't know why but every possible solution that I can think of only resulted in the background-image only appearing on the home.html.

[home.html with background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrgZY.jpg)

[all_categories.html with no background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWOvi.jpg)

First thing I tried is to have the master.html show the background image so all html files extended to it will also have background image as well. Same outcome, it only shows on the home.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myglobal.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
{% for y in H_Info %}
<body style="background-image: url({{y.bg_photo}});background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;">
    <header>
        <nav class="navibar" style="background-color:#e3c378">
            <div class="navbar-logo">
                {% for x in H_Info %}
                <a href="/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000;margin-left: 100px;">{{ x.lastname }} Portfolio</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar-menu" style="margin-right: 100px;;">
                <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="/categories/">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="main-content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>


</body>
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

But then I think maybe I should have put it on the overall css file that the master.html links to:

```
body {
  font-family: "Teko";
  background: url("../projects/img/background/Background_2.png");
}
```

I am certain I am right on the url location here. Here's my project directory:

```
personal_project/
|-- mystaticfiles/
|   |-- myglobal.css
|-- personal_project/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- asgi.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
|-- projects/
|   |-- img/
|   |   |-- background/
|   |   |   |-- Background_2.png
|   |   |-- id/
|   |   |-- projects/
|   |-- templates/
|   |   |-- about.html
|   |   |-- all_categories.html
|   |   |-- all_projects.html
|   |   |-- home.html
|   |   |-- master.html
|   |   |-- project.html
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- views.py
```

Then another thing I tried is to manually put inline css and internal css on each html files that don't have background image.

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block title %}
    My Portfolio - Categories
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% for y in H_Info %}
<body class="portfolio-page" style="background-image: url({{y.bg_photo}});background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;">
    <h1 class="text-center">Categories</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for category in categories %}
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
                <div class="position-relative thumbnail">
                    <a href="{% url 'projects_by_category' category.id %}">
                        {% with projects=category.project_info_set.all %}
                        {% if projects.exists %}
                        <img class="img-fluid cat-photo" src="{{ projects.first.artwork.url }}" alt="First Project Image">
                        {% else %}
                        <p>No projects available</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endwith %}

                    </a>
                    <h2 class="thumbnail-name position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle text-center" style="text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 white, 1px -1px 0 white, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white;user-select: none;">{{ category.category }}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block title %}
  My Portfolio - {{ category.category }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<style>
  body{
    background-image: url(../projects/img/background/Background_2.png);
  }
  
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="/categories/" class="btn btn-secondary mb-4 back-button">Back</a>

    <h1 class="text-center py-3">{{ category.category }}</h1>

    <div>
      <div class="r-all-pr">
      {% for z in projects %}
      <div class="c-all-pr">
        
        <a href="#popup{{ z.id }}">
          <img class="indiv-photo" src="{{ z.artwork.url }}" alt="{{ z.title }}" style="width:100%">
        </a>
        
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% for project in projects %}
        <div id="popup{{ project.id }}" class="popup-overlay">
          <div class="popup">
            <h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
            <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
            <div class="popup-content">
              <p>{{ project.project_description }}</p>
              <p>Created on: {{ project.date_created }}</p>
              <img class="popup-photo" src={{ project.artwork.url }} >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

both still has no background image. i double checked both the urls.py, models.py, and views.py but see no problem in it.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class About_Info(models.Model):
    long_description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/img/id', default='default')

class Contact_Links(models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    site_link = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.site_name

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Project_Info(models.Model):
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    project_description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True)
    artwork = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/img/projects', default='default')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Home_Info(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    bg_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/img/background', default='default')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}"
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import About_Info, Contact_Links, Category, Project_Info, Home_Info
# Create your views here.

def about(request):
    H_Info = Home_Info.objects.all()
    Abt_Info = About_Info.objects.all()
    Cont_Info = Contact_Links.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('about.html')
    context ={
        'Abt_Info':Abt_Info,
        'Cont_Info':Cont_Info,
        'H_Info': H_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def project(request, project_id):
    H_Info = Home_Info.objects.all()
    P_Info = Project_Info.objects.get(id=project_id)
    template=loader.get_template('project.html')
    context = {
        'P_Info':P_Info,
        'H_Info': H_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def home(request):
    H_Info = Home_Info.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('home.html')
    context = {
        'H_Info': H_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

#NEW
def category(request):
    H_Info = Home_Info.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('all_categories.html')
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'H_Info': H_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def projects_by_category(request, category_id):
    H_Info = Home_Info.objects.all()
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=category_id)
    projects = Project_Info.objects.filter(cat=category)
    template = loader.get_template('all_projects.html')
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'projects': projects,
        'H_Info': H_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def master(request):
    H_Info = Home_Info.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('master.html')
    context = {
        'H_Info': H_Info,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/',views.about),
    path('projects/<int:project_id>/', views.project, name='project'),
    path('',views.home),
    path('categories/', views.category, name='categories'),
    path('categories/<int:category_id>/', views.projects_by_category, name='projects_by_category'),

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am almost done with my website. I just couldn't fix this background image problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).